# Substitution method in an initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives, initial-value-problems

... Is it possible to  make the substitution   $y(x)= z(x)+\sqrt{x}$ and represent the solution y(x) of the following initial value problem for all $x \geqslant1$ in terms of the new function z(x)?
\begin{cases}
  y'=x-y^2  \\\\
  y(0)=0
 \end{cases}
In other words, naming  Y(x) the solution of the the initial value problem above , and Z(x) that of the following problem, supposing that solving the first problem  we have found the value Y(1) ,is it true that $Z(x)=Y(x)$-$\sqrt{x}$ for  $x \geqslant1$  ?
\begin{cases}
z'=-z^2-2 \sqrt{x}\cdot z-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\\
z(1)=Y(1)-1
\end{cases}
I ask this question because I have found that Z(x) must tend to 0 as x tends to infinity for any -1<z(1)<0 and I'm not sure that this implies that $Y(x)-\sqrt{x}$ tends to 0. I think that the unicity of the solutions Y(x) and  Z(x)  is enough to state that that Z(x)=Y(x)-$\sqrt{x}$, because if Y(x) satisfies the first problem then Y(x)-$\sqrt{x}$ satisfies the second one. Is this argument correct?
Thanks in advance for the answer.

...

Answer (score 0):

For large $x$ and small $z$ the equation is dominated by the terms $z'=-2\sqrt{x}z$ with the solution $z=Ce^{-\frac43x^{3/2}}$ which converges rapidly to zero.

Seeing the equation as Riccati equation and setting $y=\frac{u'}{u}$ leads to $u''=xu$ which has the Airy functions as solution. Additionally, the second order WKB approximation gives for $x\gg 1$
$$
u\approx x^{-\frac14}(Ae^{\frac23x^{3/2}}+Be^{-\frac23x^{3/2}})
$$
which leads back to
$$
y(x)\approx-\frac1{4x}
+\sqrt{x}\frac{Ae^{\frac23x^{3/2}}-Be^{-\frac23x^{3/2}}}{Ae^{\frac23x^{3/2}}+Be^{-\frac23x^{3/2}}}
=\sqrt{x}-\frac1{4x}-\sqrt{x}\frac{-2Be^{-\frac43x^{3/2}}}{A+Be^{-\frac43x^{3/2}}}
$$